# Where do I POST and store simple JSON data on a wordpress database using the REST API?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am looking for some insight on where to store user JSON data on Wordpress via the REST API.

I am working on a single-page-application website that will allow users to create a watchlist of movies and click whether they liked the movie. I am using the Wordpress REST API and want to be able to store the users likes and watchlists on the Wordpress database.

For example, using the list of liked movies, I created the below custom end point in my functions.php file:

```
add_action('rest_api_init','add_user_likes');

function add_user_likes(){
    register_rest_route(
    'v1/user_likes','/(?P<id>\d+)',[[
        'methods'=> 'GET',
        'callback'=>'get_user_likes'
    ],
    [
        'methods'=> 'POST',
        'callback'=>'post_user_likes'
    ]]);
};
```

I am attempting to POST from the front end a simple object holding post_id and post_title.

Here are is my callback for the GET method:

```
function get_user_likes(){
    return array(
    "post_id"=>$post_id,
    "post_title"=>$post_title
    );
}
```

And for the POST method:

```
function post_user_likes(WP_REST_Request $req){
    $body = $req->get_json_params();
    $post_title = $body->post_title;
    $post_id = $body->post_id;
    return [
        $body
         ];
};
```

Using Firefox's RESTer plugin, I am getting status 200 for both methods, but none of my POST attempts are actually saving.

I've spent a couple of days researching how to write the callbacks for each method with no luck. It occurred to me that I am not actually assigning the user data a place to be saved in Wordpress.

After doing some research, I haven't really found an answer on where this JSON data would best be stored.

If someone could provide some insight on where and how to store user JSON data on WP, that would be great. Also, if anyone could provide help on writing callbacks to do this, that would be great.

Comment: Do you want to store the likes attached to the post (movie has XX likes) or to the user (user liked movie XYZ)? If you want to attach a watchlist to the user ... the functions available for manipulating User Metadata are: add_user_meta(), update_user_meta(), delete_user_meta() and get_user_meta().

Comment: They should be stored under user. I didn't know if that was an option so opted to store the data under a custom end point referencing user id.

Comment: Alright, have a look here, this might point you into the right direction: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/users/working-with-user-metadata/

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Much appreciated.